# how to pass username and email from GAS to HTML form

Tags: google-apps-script

im trying to pass username and email to the html form which is called in doGet.

```
function  doGet(e) {
// e has url parameters which contain username and email
   var id = e.parameter;
var name = e.postData.contents.split("&")[0];
// after a bunch of splitting ill have two vars
var name and var email, how do i pass this two vars to the index, 

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(
            HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

this is index

```
<form id="uploaderForm">
        <label for="uploaderForm">Upload plusieur fichiers</label>
        <div>
//both inputs will be hidden, and will contain the values of name and email variables that i have in doGet
            <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName"
                placeholder="nom">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmail"
                placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadFiles()">
        </div>
    </form>
```

to sum up, i have two vars in doGet, var name and var email, i wanna pass them to the html index so i can use them as input values , so that the user doesnt have to manually type them

Answer (score 1):

**solution 1:**
i havent completely tested this yet but im too excited, i spent two days on this i even had nightmares about it last night, so this is how i passed variables to the html form to use in the input

```
function  doGet(e) {
   var id = e.parameter;
var name = e.postData.contents.split("&")[0];
var email = e.postData.contents.split("&")[1];
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
template.myVar = name.split("=")[1];
template.email = email.split("=")[1];
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(
            HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


function doPost(e) {
return doGet(e);
}
```

and in the html , you can simply call the variables using   or   whatever you named it like so

```
<input type="text" name="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmail"
            placeholder=<?= email ?> value=<?= email ?>>
```

the username and email are recieved from a local webpage form that has a post method, so generally im passing username and email to the  GAS from my local web page , and then passing it to the html page of the GAS.

**solution 2**
if you are calling the google script app using  and want to pass parameters or variables to the google app script, you can attach them to the URL in the iframe like so

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/.../exec?name=value1&email=value2...">
```

and then you can access name and email parameters in the google app script in the doGet function like so

```
function doGet(e) {
var name = e.parameter.name;
var email = e.parameter.email;
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
template.myVar = name;
template.email = email;
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```